# Running javascript in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How can I add a script to an `iframe`?

I wrote something:

```
doc = $frame[0].contentDocument ||  $frame[0].contentWindow.document;
$body = $("body", doc);
$head = $("head", doc);
$js = $("<script type='text/javascript' />");
$js[0].type = "text/javascript";
$head.append($js);
```

and it is my function that is working textarea keyup event.

```
function addJS() {
  js = js_textarea.val();
  $js.html(js);             
}
```

However this is not working, code is adding to script tags but not running the browser? How can I solve this problem.
(I already tried `eval()`)

**Edit, these are my codes:**

```
$frame = $('<iframe id="frame">');
$("#preview").html($frame);

doc = $frame[0].contentDocument ||  $frame[0].contentWindow.document;

$body = $("body", doc);
$head = $("head", doc);

$js = $("<script type='text/javascript' />");
$js[0].type = "text/javascript";

$head.append($js);

htmlEditor.on("change", function() {
    addJS();
});

function addJS() {
    js = $("#js_textarea").val();
    $js.html(js); 
}
```

Comment: First of all: is the `iframe` content from your domain? or if not, do you have permission to it?

Comment: Yes, it is in my page and I created this.

Comment: Not asking if the code is on your page; asking if the `src` of the `iframe` points to the same server as the main page.

Comment: Is the iframe's original source on your domain? Like `http://yoursite.com/youriframe.html`?

Comment: @Amadan I updated codes in my question

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. I guess you'd need to create a new `<script>` tag, or use `doc.eval(js)`. Also, if you're going the `script` route, I believe you need to create it in the `doc` context (`$('<script type="text/javascript"></script>', doc)`).

Comment: @Amadan `doc.eval('alert(2)')` is not working.

Comment: @Teemu, you are right man. JS codes are not working in the page which comes from textarea.

Comment: try using $.parseHTML() and $js = "<script type='text/javascript' />"; this way $head.append($.parseHTML($js));

Comment: @rjdmello it didint work... Is it possible to make this using with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work. Scripts are immutable. The "HTML" of a script is parsed and evaluated at the time the script is appended to the DOM. After that, you can even remove the script tag, and the script itself will still work. Hence, also changing the script text does not cause a new script being parsed and executed.

You can add some content to `script` tag before it is appended to the DOM. You can test this by inserting the line below into your code just before appending `$js`.

```
$js.html('alert("foo");');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, well, If I want to make this with using PHP, can I do this?

Comment: You can send a new script with PHP, that'll offer you a chance to validate the user given string too.

Comment: I have already tried to use PHP. It is harder than using JS. With using PHP, there are one and big problem. I can't handle iframe. For example, I can't add script tag to iframe with PHP. If can solve this, I use PHP.

Comment: Well, that's a subject for another question. In the meanwhile, you maybe want to accept the answer, though it says "you can't do what you want".

Comment: I did CSS and HTML editor but I couldnt do JS compiler. Thanks.